# Why is sed not substituting for after a match?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file which is named as text.csv and the contents are mentioned below

10 Tiny Toes

This is ThaT

5 funny 0

one Two Three

Tree Twice

I am trying to substitute the numbers by enclosing parentheses around so the expected output is

(1)(0) Tiny Toes

This is ThaT

(5) funny (0)

one Two Three

Tree Twice

I am using sed command as

```
sed 's/[0-9]/(&)/g' text.csv
```

Then it get the correct output , but then i tried giving the following

```
sed 's/[0-9]*/(&)/g' text.csv
```

Then it gives the following output.

(10) ()T()i()n()y() ()T()o()e()s()

()T()h()i()s() ()i()s() ()T()h()a()T()

(5) ()f()u()n()n()y() (0)

()o()n()e() ()T()w()o() ()T()h()r()e()e()

()T()r()e()e() ()T()w()i()c()e()

So presence of * would mean that, the immediately preceding character should be searched and replaced with (&), but that's not happening. Where am i wrong with using * for searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x*` means any sequence of **0** or more `x`es. It's short for `x\{0,\}`. So it matches on the empty string as well. To match on **1** or more, it's `\{1,\}` which, if you enable extended regexp with `-E` (only some `sed` implementations) can be shortened to `+`.

Note that `[0-9]` often means any collating elements that sort between character `0` and character `9`, which depending on the locale, OS or `sed` implementation doesn't means only `0123456789`.

So:

```
sed 's/[0123456789]\{1,\}/(&)/g'
```

Or:

```
sed -E 's/[0123456789]+/(&)/g'
```

Comment: let me try this but interestingly a zero occurrence is being considered a match so then why mentioning [0-9][0-9]* works perfectly ? Had i put two spaces between the words, would it have resulted in a similar behavior ?

Comment: @userx, well of course `xx*` is `x` followed by 0 or more `x`es, so it's 1 or more `x`es like `x\{1,\}`. None of that has anything to do with *spaces*.